# How can I show a function that converts a tuple to a non-tuple is bijective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have the below function I came up with and would like to show that it is injective and surjective (bijective). How can I do this?

$$f\bigg(\bigg(\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}\bigg)\bigg) = (a+c)+\sqrt7(b+d)$$

To prove the function is injective, I tried supposing $\ f\bigg(\bigg(\frac{a_1}{b_1}, \frac{c_1}{d_1}\bigg)\bigg) = \ f\bigg(\bigg(\frac{a_2}{b_2}, \frac{c_2}{d_2}\bigg)\bigg)$ and then showing that $(a_1+c_1)+\sqrt7(b_1+d_1) = (a_2+c_2)+\sqrt7(b_2+d_2)$.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this.

EDIT: Domain is $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$, range is \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why would it be?

Comment: @Berci It isn't bijective? That's what I am trying to find out. Whether it is or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with f. Let r = $\sqrt7$.
2 + 2r = f(1/1,1/1) = f(2/2,1/1) = 3 + 3r.

It is not surjective because the range of f is a subset of the algebraic numbers and $\pi$ is not algebraic.  Thus the codomain of f cannot be R.

To fix the problem, require a,b,c,d to be integers with positive b,d and a/b, c/d to be in lowest terms.  Now f is well defined.

Its range is { n + mr : n integer, m positive integer }.
It is not injective because f(a/b,c/d) = f(c/d,a/b).

Comment: Ahh, yes. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To show Injectivity it suffices to show that $\forall x,y \in Dom(f)$ if $f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$. However, keep in mind that the choice of $x$ and $y$ must be arbitrary. In your solution, it does seem to be injective.

In order to show surjectivity you have to show $\forall y\in Ran(f), \exists x\in Dom(b)$. However, you must specify $f:A \to B$. That is, what kind of map is $f$, from what set to what set. Is it from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \mathbb R \to \mathbb Z$, etc.

Comment: Ok. I seem to have got the idea of proving that it is injective. However, I don't see how I can prove that $\forall y \in Ran(f), \exists x \in Dom(b)$. That seems especially hard to prove in the case of my function.

Comment: Since $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$, it can not be surjective. Furthermore, if it is not surjective, then it is not bijective.

Comment: Yes, but I mean more in general. The range was artificial, I will fix it. How could I show that a function like this is surjective?

Comment: If you are given a non-general function. That is, $f(x)$, with an argument $x$, then solve the function for $x$ in terms of $y$ and compare the new found domain with the domain of the initial function and see if there are any jump discontinuities. If not, then it is surjective. However, in general surjectivity is relatively tough to prove. So sometimes it requires thinking outside the box.